# Ubuntu 16.04: Log in problem when using prime-select intel and adding /usr/lib/nvidia-396 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: nvidia, environment-variables, paths, display-manager

I'm doing some computation with my GPU (GTX 970) so I decided to use my integrated card from my CPU (i7-4790K) to display my 2 screens, hence I used prime-select intel to do so.

In doing so it seems that the path to nvidia tools is no longer available, so I decided to add /usr/lib/nvidia-396 to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH. First I put it on my ~/.bashrc but by doing so the path is not available to programs launch from the DisplayManager. I then decided to put it on /etc/profile.d/my-env-var.sh with a bunch of others environment variables that I need everywhere like anaconda/cuda/cudnn.

What is strange is that if I add /usr/lib/nvidia-396 to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my /etc/profile.d/my-env-var.sh then I'm stucked into a login loop. The same thing goes for ~/.profile. The only place it worked for me is in ~/.bashrc but that do not allow my to use DisplayManager programs with this LD_LIBRARY_PATH defined. Hence Nvidia is not find unless I add it manually if the program allow it.

What I don't understand is why does /usr/lib/nvidia-396 make my login fail. I tried to add other random paths (like /usr/lib/lapack, ~/dir_example) to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my /etc/profile.d/my-env-var.sh and it works fine.

I know two workarounds, like launching every apps that I need form bash or add manually the path in each program that I write but it's cumbersome. I would really like to understand what makes it crashed.

Here are my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
PATH = home/julesd/lib/Modules/bin:/home/julesd/bin:/home/julesd/.local/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin:/home/julesd/lib/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/lib/nvidia-396:/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64
```

Here is my ~/.xsession-errors for the login loop

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: unity7 main process (13638) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13668) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13698) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13728) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13769) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13799) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13829) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13859) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13889) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13919) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (13949) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 respawning too fast, stopped
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (13420) terminated with status 1
upstart: logrotate main process (13250) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (13433) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (13480) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (13481) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (13482) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-printers main process (13490) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (13491) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process (13510) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (13358) killed by TERM signal
```